# How is it made that NIC has name eth0 not usb0?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, pi-3b+, qemu

Raspberry Pi network card is internally a USB card. Why then it has name `eth0` and not `usb0`?

I need to find a code, which is responsible for this.

I am simulating Raspberry Pi with QEMU and having a situation, when my simulated card is sometimes identified as `usb0` and sometimes as `eth0`, I would like to gain a control over it.

Comment: this is an XY question ... it asks about something other that the actual problem that you are trying to solve ... please focus your question to the actual problem ... also your question is not about the Raspberry Pi ... it is a Linux question

Comment: *my simulated card is sometimes identified as usb0 and sometimes as eth0* - your simulation must be flawed, or you change something, if it isn't consistent